# Firma SOAP en PHP con certificado digital

Tags: php, soap, certificado

Al final, antes de tirar la toalla o de volverme definitivamente loca recurro a vosotros para ver si algún alma caritativa me puede echar un cable.

Antes de que se me pase trato de hacer la conexión desde PHP y decir que llevo googleando y probando desde hace un par de meses y no consigo sacar nada en claro, hay alguna pregunta parecida a esta pero sin respuesta, traté con varias rutinas pero sin éxito.

El tema en cuestión es comunicar a al Ministerio de Fomento de España los traslados (viajes) que está previsto realizar en los próximos días por medio de un procedimiento SOAP.

Para poder operar con ellos hay que enviarles un correo a la dirección registrovtc@fomento.es, indicando en el asunto “ALTA REGISTRO VTC” con la siguiente información:

- NIF de la entidad (persona jurídica) que va a realizar las comunicaciones
- Razón social de la entidad que va a realizar las comunicaciones
- Número de serie (“SERIALNUMBER”) del certificado utilizado para las comunicaciones
- Entorno en el que se solicita el alta (INTEGRACIÓN y/o PRODUCCIÓN)
- Dirección (o rango) IP desde la que se realiza la conexión (sólo en caso de solicitar alta en el entorno de integración)
- Adjuntar  al correo una copia de la parte pública del certificado que se utilizará para la comunicación de servicios, de forma que se pueda comprobar que la información suministrada es correcta y comprobar que es reconocido correctamente por el Registro.

La información que facilitan para la especificación de la firma electrónica es la siguiente:

Las llamadas al servicio web deberán implementar el estándar “Web Services Security” (WS-Security), garantizando la autenticidad e integridad de los datos remitidos. La confidencialidad se garantizará al utilizarse HTTPS como protocolo de transporte.

Los mensajes deberán firmarse con un certificado de entidad único para cada entidad (persona jurídica) autorizada.

El mensaje SOAP se enviará junto con los datos de firma digital XML y un BinarySecurityToken que contenga la parte pública del certificado utilizado. 
Se muestra a continuación un ejemplo de petición SOAP, con el nodo de firma WS-Security:

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:vtc="http://mfom.com/vtc"> 
    <soapenv:Header>
   <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="X509-8E8323448EEC46F5B41559339975629101">MIIGoDCC……………..……UNAD/Mif8A=</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
<ds:Signature Id="SIG-8E8323448EEC46F5B41559339975632105" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="soapenv vtc" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:CanonicalizationMethod><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/><ds:Reference URI="#id-8E8323448EEC46F5B41559339975630104"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="vtc" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:Transform></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><ds:DigestValue>cf2SHSHaZhYkbe6ypSbJAT+FsLM=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue>dvxXH………………...ctviyCg==</ds:SignatureValue><ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-8E8323448EEC46F5B41559339975629102"><wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-8E8323448EEC46F5B41559339975629103"><wsse:Reference URI="#X509-8E8323448EEC46F5B41559339975629101" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/></wsse:SecurityTokenReference></ds:KeyInfo></ds:Signature></wsse:Security></soapenv:Header> 
    <soapenv:Body wsu:Id="id-8E8323448EEC46F5B41559339975630104" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"> 
    <vtc:qaltavtc> 
    <header fecha="2019-01-01T12:29:00" version="1.0" versionsender="1.0"/> 
    <body> 
    <vtcservicio cgmunicontrato="079" cgmunifin="079" cgmuniinicio="079" cgmunilejano="079" cgprovcontrato="28" cgprovfin="28" cgprovinicio="28" cgprovlejano="28" direccionfin="destino" direccioninicio="origen" direccionlejano="lejano" fcontrato="2019-01-01" ffin="2019-12-31" fprevistainicio="2019-12-31T15:00:00" matricula="9999-ZZZ" nifarrendador="99999999R" nifarrendatario="123456789" niftitular="11111111H" nombarrendador="ARRENDADOR" nombarrendatario="ARRENDATARIO" nombtitular="TITULAR"/> 
    </body> 
    </vtc:qaltavtc> 
    </soapenv:Body> 
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

El código anterior es para la comunicación de un nuevo traslado (Alta de servicio), las otras funciones que existen son:

```
[0] => rconsultavtc ConsultaDeServicio(qconsultavtc $pqconsultavtc)
[1] => raltavtc AltaDeServicio(qaltavtc $pqaltavtc)
[2] => ranulacionvtc AnulacionDeServicio(qanulacionvtc $pqiniciovtc)
[3] => rmodificacionvtc ModificacionDeServicio(qmodificacionvtc $pqmodificacionvtc)
[4] => riniciovtc InicioDeServicio(qiniciovtc $pqiniciovtc)
```

Posiblemente la función más sencilla de llamar sea la primera (ConsultaDeServicio) dado que sólo hay que pasarle la información de fecha="2019-01-01T12:29:00" version="1.0" versionsender="1.0" en la cabecera y el idservicio="xxxxxxx", donde xxxxxx es un número único que se asigna a cada servicio al darlo de alta.

He probado desde SOAP UI la función de Consulta de servicio y no da ningún problema.

El acceso se realiza mediante el certificado digital, no existe un par usuario contraseña, que es lo más extendido por la Web.

Probé sin éxito (supongo que definiría algo mal) soap-wsse, nusoap-0.9.5, xmlseclibs y no se cuantas otras cosas mas.

Si alguien tiene una idea de por donde pueden ir los tiros le quedaría eternamente agradecida si comparte su sabiduría.

Haciendo caso a las sugerencias edito (lo siento es la primera vez que pregunto y estoy un poco pez), ahora que no se si podre borrar el comentario para evitar duplicidades.

Las direcciones de acceso al servicio web en los entornos de Integración y Producción son:
Entorno de Integración
https://presede.fomento.gob.es/MFOM.Services.VTC.Server/VTCPort?wsdl
Puerto de conexión:  443
Entorno de Producción
https://sede.fomento.gob.es/MFOM.Services.VTC.Server/VTCPort?wsdl
Puerto de conexión: 443

Lo que pretendo hacer es una página web programada en PHP en la cual introduciendo el id del servicio me muestre la información asociada al mismo (función ConsultaDeServicio) y otra que permita indicar el inicio del mismo (InicioDeServicio), a las dos le pasaría por POST el id del servicio y recuperaria la respuesta obtenida.

Me estrello, una y otra vez con la llamada con la petición de datos creo que por el certificado digital, he probado con otros métodos SOAP sacados por Internet (como la conversión de grados centigrados a farenhait) y no había problemas, pero claro tampoco había certificados por el medio.

Muchas gracias a todos, estoy abierta a cualquier sugerencia.

Comment: En lugar de agregar información en comentarios puedes editar tu pregunta, para agregar cualquier cosa que se te haya olvidado :)

Comment: No te vuelvas loca, ni tires la toalla, que algún alma caritativa aquí te ayudará sin duda. Leí tu pregunta, pero no logré entender cuál es el problema que tienes ni dónde está el problema. Dinos lo que quieres hacer, con qué código, qué respuesta tienes, de qué forma has depurado la respuesta, etc. Para todo ello pulsa en [edit]. Evita poner datos sensibles en el código, como certificados, tokens, ids, etc.

Comment: Gracias Riaven y A. Cedano. Ya edité la pregunta y al final cuento un poco lo que quiero, código para el Soap no tengo mucho... que funcione, con fallos tengo muchos, pero creo despistan más que ayudan. Nuevamente gracias.